# Detect change in localStorage in same tab

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Is there any way to detect change in localStorage but in the same tab it was changed in?

Comment: Can you please provide more details, maybe share your codebase try creating a condesandbox.io snippet so that the community members who are trying to help have a better idea and can guide you better.

Answer (score -2):

Inside your script add an event listener on `storage`

```
window.addEventListener("storage", function () {
    // Storage updated.
}, false);
```

Comment: I think "but in the same tab it was changed in" is clear enough to explain that I want to detect it in the same tab.